# Could not Find TensorRT

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorrt, stable-baselines

I'm using stable_baseline3 for RL purpose, and during the installation of my setup I have installed both pytorch and tensorflow, the former before the other one. When I import a library that needed tensorflow, i got the following warning
*W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT*

This do not impact my workflow and all work as expected, but i  would like to understand the issue and a feasible way to solve it

This is my relevant python packages version:

```
-tensorflow                           2.12.0
-tensorflow-estimator                 2.12.0
-tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem         0.32.0
-tensorflow-probability               0.20.0
-tensorrt                             8.6.1
-tensorrt-bindings                    8.6.1
-tensorrt-libs                        8.6.1

-torch                                2.0.1
-torch-tb-profiler                    0.4.1
-torchaudio                           2.0.2
-torchview                            0.2.6
-torchvision                          0.15.2

-nvidia-cublas-cu11                   11.10.3.66
-nvidia-cublas-cu12                   12.1.3.1
-nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11               11.7.101
-nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11               11.7.99
-nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11             11.7.99
-nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12             12.1.105
-nvidia-cudnn-cu11                    8.6.0.163
-nvidia-cudnn-cu12                    8.9.1.23
-nvidia-cufft-cu11                    10.9.0.58
-nvidia-curand-cu11                   10.2.10.91
-nvidia-cusolver-cu11                 11.4.0.1
-nvidia-cusparse-cu11                 11.7.4.91
-nvidia-ml-py                         11.525.112
-nvidia-nccl-cu11                     2.14.3
-nvidia-nvtx-cu11                     11.7.91
-nvidia-pyindex                       1.0.9
-nvidia-tensorrt                      99.0.0

GPU driver:
Driver Version: 470.199.02   CUDA Version: 11.4
```

I searched on this website some solution but i did not find any solution (or good explanation of the problem), tried different versions of CUDA and python packages.